# React conditional rendering components in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using MomentJS in a project which takes data from a JSON file and outputs time.

#### time-example.json

`"delay": "PT4M",`

In my component, I am able to successfully render time as minutes for various data points from JSON:

#### delay.jsx

```
 <span>{moment.duration(gapTime, "seconds").asMinutes()}</span>
```

Now, I am trying to write a ternary statement which will render different CSS styles based on time.

If the time is < 300 (less than 5 minutes), I want to display a certain CSS style and if it is greater, I want to display another.

```
const Delay = ({ data }) => {
  const [gapTime, setGapTime] = useState(data.gap);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {gapTime < 300 ? (
          <div className={style.boxLow}>
            <span>{moment.duration(gapTime, "seconds").asMinutes()}</span>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className={style.boxHigh}>
            <span>{moment.duration(gapTime, "seconds").asMinutes()}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Delay;
```

It's a pretty simple conditional statement but for some reason, it will only display the second class in the ternary statement (boxHigh). Is there a mistake I am making with Moment in the ternary to set the initial time?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?"

Comment: @Galupuf I clarified the statement. I will only render the style of second part of the statement.

Comment: Couple of obvious things, how sure are you that gapTime is ever < 300? Also if the only difference is the className why not just put the ternary in the className expression?

Comment: "_React conditional rendering components in map function_" I not able to see any `.map()` method being used in your shared code? Also, what is `style.boxLow` here?

Comment: @palaѕн The item is rendered in another component. style is imported like this: ```import style from './style.module.less'```.     boxLow is the classname. The time is rendering correctly in the .map component, just not the style.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that you are pretty sure that `gapTime` is < 300 in some cases but it is still showing `style.boxHigh`? Also, can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening? Use some hard coded array data just for the demo purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your component isn't rerendering because it's state didn't change. It's still set to what you initialized it to, even though your `data.gap` prop might have changed. If you want your component to rerender/update when your props change, don't set state to your props, but instead just use the props directly.

If you want your component to rerender every time `data.gap` changes, use the prop directly

```
const Delay = ({ data }) => {

return (
  <>
    <div>
      {props.data.gap < 300 ? (
        <div className={style.boxLow}>
         <span>{moment.duration(gapTime, "seconds").asMinutes()}</span>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className={style.boxHigh}>
          <span>{moment.duration(gapTime, "seconds").asMinutes()}</span>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  </>
);
};

export default Delay;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```js
<div className={gapTime < 300 ?style.boxLow:style.boxHigh}>
    <span>{moment.duration(gapTime, "seconds").asMinutes()}</span>
</div>
```